# Fit background-image to content in Qt

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet

Is there any way to define a fit-to-content background-image in stylesheet?

Such as if the host widget is 40x40 and the images is 100x100 it will not be clipped but rather scaled to fit the 40x40 area.

Comment: Are you expecting something like that from CSS? And have you tried to code such behavior?

Comment: Oh I know I can code it. Just wanted to see if there's a magical keyword I wasn't familiar with.... :-)

Comment: would border-image: url(:/img/myimage.png); work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I had no choice but to write my own derived QWidget class, override paintEvent and draw the image with the rectangle of the widget's geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the background size to 'contain'
assume your div's id foo

```
#foo {
  background:url(image.png) contain;
}
```

I think this link could help
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Comment: unfortunately "contain" is not recognized.